# Push files to GitLab Repo without cloning

Tags: git, gitlab

Can I commit and push files or folder to a a GitLab Repo without cloning it first?

I have a very large repo where i want to add only few single files with each commit.

I already tried

- `git clone -n --depth 1 ...git`

and

- `git add myfile --ignore-removal`
- `git commit`
- `git push`

But that still takes along time and transferring ~ 2GB. The `.git` folder alone seems to be huge after cloning.

So is there a efficient way to add single files to a GitLab Repo without cloning it first?

Comment: Once you have cloned, Git add-commmit-push is _very_ efficient.  Does this repo have many branches?

Comment: no only the main branch

Comment: You can upload a file via the web interface or even using API. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitlab%5D+upload+file

Comment: Well then there is no better Git way to do what you're describing. But maybe you could use GitLab CLI / API or the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to clone the repo, you can use [Web IDE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide/) to modify existing files or [upload](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide/#upload-a-new-file) new ones.